# When using Microsoft Test Manager 2010 with SfTS, can Acceptance Tests be reused for regression testing?

Tags: tfs, scrum, microsoft-test-manager

We are moving our projects to TFS 2010 using the [SfTS v3 (Scrum for Team System)](http://www.scrumforteamsystem.co.uk/ProcessGuidance/v3) template. We need to understand how Microsoft Test Manager is supposed to be used in **this** Scrum process.

*Specific scenario & question:*

The QA manager uses Test Manager to create a test plan. This aligns to our sprint. In the sprint, he create Acceptance Test WIs (Work Items) that are core to the functionality. These pass for the specific sprint. On the next sprint, he makes another test plan. The Acceptance Test WIs from the previous sprint and needed again as part of the regression testing.

Does the Acceptance Test (AC) state have to be "passed" so the Product Backlog Item (PBI) can be closed? Can the AC WI be reused between sprints?

Comment: Were you aware that Microsoft has a Scrum template as well? I don't know how the SfTS "Acceptance Test" type works with MTM. Perhaps it replaces the Test Case work item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the Acceptance Test (AC) state have to be "passed" so the Product
>   Backlog Item (PBI) can be closed?

Yes

> Can the AC WI be reused between sprints?

Of course for regression and to do this you will need to copy the test cases from sprint to another sprint but remember this will not make a deep copy and will make reference for the previous sprint in reporting, you can use the following tool for bulk copy 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72576517-821b-46c2-aa1a-fab940752292

Visual Studio 11 Beta will support bulk deep copy without reference and it's available now for production, so I recommended using it.
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads

Comment: Will this work with the Acceptance Test work item he'll be using? It's not a Test Case work item.

Comment: I guess yes! what the different between Acceptance Test work item and Test case work item?

Comment: I don't know - I don't use that template. That's why I felt you were perhaps too certain of the answer: maybe you haven't used it either. The OP is not talking about the Microsoft Scrum template.

Comment: Oh I got it, But he talks about MTM so I guess it's the same Test case, maybe the bulk tool will not work, but he still can copy the Test Case (Acceptance Test) in MTM

Comment: While I appreciate the response and the related links (leading me to Anna Russo's blog post), I trust you understand I'm not marking this as the answer. I am seeking experience from users of SfTS which is not Microsoft Scrum. @M.Radwan, your points are helpful.